# How does xgboost select which feature to split on?

Tags: random-forest, cart, boosting

Pretty straightforward question. Does it check every feature and pick the one that maximizes some split-quality metric (like a decision tree), or does it just select a feature at random (like a random forest)?

Comment: XGBoost applies Weighted Quantile Sketch [see this math-friendly video](https://youtu.be/oRrKeUCEbq8?t=461) as approximate algorithm to speed up feature selection. And before that it may run [subsampling](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#general-parameters) such as `subsample` and `colsample_bytree/level/node` to improve performance at specified stage. Question: Why would subsampling not affect the splitting criterion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the [xgboost paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf) is a little underprecise on this point but I will share my interpretation of what they describe. This understanding is not based on reading the code so take it with a grain of salt and hope for a braver soul to put a finer point on this anwer (which I found because I also had it after reading the paper).

The lead-in to the discussion of the approximate algorithm for choosing a split point says

> . . . a split
>   finding algorithm enumerates over all the possible splits on
>   all the features"

and then goes on to say that this exhaustive search is unfeasible for large datasets and also does not interact well with distributed training so that an approximate algorithm is needed.  This algorithm is described in some detail in the appendix and it is (I believe) specifically an algorithm for finding candidate split points for a given feature.

Their description of how this approximate algorithm is used says

> To summarize, the algorithm first proposes candidate
>   splitting points according to percentiles of feature
>   distribution (a specific criteria will be given in Sec. 3.3).
>   The algorithm then maps the continuous features into buckets
>   split by these candidate points, aggregates the statistics
>   and finds the best solution among proposals based on the
>   aggregated statistics.

I believe that this means that candidate splits are proposed for every single feature in the dataset and that all of these candidate splits are inspected to find the optimal one. This means that the method of finding splits really is an approximate form of the algorithm that inspects every single feature and every single split to find the best one but that the approximation only happens at the level of the splits proposed for each feature. Every single feature is still inspected.

Answer (score 3):

The complete algorithm is outlined in the [xgboost](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf) paper, which also provides this summary:

> We summarize an approximate framework, which resembles the ideas proposed in past literatures, in Alg. 2. To summarize, the algorithm first proposes candidate splitting points according to percentiles of feature distribution (a specific criteria will be given in Sec. 3.3). The algorithm then maps the continuous features into buckets split by these candidate points, aggregates the statistics and finds the best solution among proposals based on the aggregated statistics.

Since it's finding the best solution (feature and split) from some set of proposed solutions, we can infer that it is (approximately) optimizing some metric, and that the selection of features and splits is not at random. More complete information is provided in the paper.

It's also worth noting that random forest doesn't simply select features at random -- for each split, random forest selects a subset of features, and then chooses the best split from among the random subset.

Comment: It would have been nice if the question was answered from a different perspective, without quoting directly from a (rather technical) paper -- especially since the answer assumes that the OP didn't read or trying reading it.

Comment: @cosmosis There's a button below this answer labeled "Add Another Answer."

Comment: I don't have another answer -- I'm looking for one.

Comment: I had the same question as OP after having read this section of the paper carefully a number of times. I think it is aggressive to assume the OP has not read the paper and I do not think the provided quote is really clear on what the answer to the question is.

Comment: @JoelDodge There's no indication in the question that OP read the paper. If the question were "I have a question about section [whatever] of the XGBoost paper, because I don't understand what they mean by [something]" one could provide something more insightful: if this were the case, there would be context about what the OP doesn't understand, and an answerer could elaborate upon it. This answer does provide evidence that the splits aren't random, as proposed by OP, and points to the part of the paper with more elaboration.

Comment: OP specifically asks about whether FEATURES are chosen at random and the method for selecting which features to consider is neither addressed in the provided quote nor really explicitly addressed in the paper.

Comment: @JoelDodge It's clear that you have a dramatically different reading of the question and my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The splitting algorithm for XgBoost is pre-sorted and histogram (which is what Joel described in his answer). If you search with these keywords, you will understand them better. Also, my understanding is that to figure out the best split, Xgboost scores the split candidates by using the equation obtained from the derivative of objective function.

Comment: Does XGBoost have to re-sort the statistics after each split? Why not?