# How XGBoost and Adaboost select the most important features?

Tags: boosting, adaboost

I know perfectly that random forest computes the most important variables using the mean decrease Gini, but what about Adaboost and XGBoost?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299859/how-does-xgboost-select-which-feature-to-split-on/299869#299869