# How XGBoost chooses between two features that gives the same information?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, boosting, importance

I have 10 variables in a dataset (`X1`, `X2`, .., `X10`) plus the binary target variable (`Y`). When I train a model with `xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier()` and then plot the feature importances with `xgboost.plot_importance(my_model, importance_type='gain)`, I get that `X1` variable is the most important (~70%) for this first model. However, if I drop the `X1` variable, train again, I get the `X2` variable is the most important (~70%) in this second model with no significant differences in the final performance of both models. So, I compute the linear correlation between those two hoping it's high and I just get -22% (and this -22% makes business sense, so no problem with that)

**My question**

What criteria XGBoost uses to choose X1 over X2 when are both variables present? (And it gives a feature importance to X1 near 70% and to X2 near 0%), does this suggest that XGBoost already gets all the information of X2 using X1? If yes, how?

Comment: Unusual behaviour indeed! (+1) Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is what $0\%$ importance for `X2` in the presence of `X1` suggests.

Now, the "how" is somewhat open-ended but the basic "how" is that the inclusion of `X1` allows any interactions of `X2` with other variables as well as the variation of (a discretised) `X2` itself to be adequately captured in (a discretised form of) `X1`. Thus, `X1` simply gives better splits than `X2` so `X1` is (almost) always picked instead of `X2`. The thread [How does xgboost select which feature to split on?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299859) gives a further discussion on this point but the point to emphasise it that we do a greedy search and pick the optimal split.

Side-note: The "*-22% correlation*" actually might be very strong in certain domains,  it might even be the case that the correlation is not higher simply because `X2` is "noisy" (and thus once more we should favour `X1`). To that extent, when using tree-based learners, we use the ordering of the feature variable so linear correlation (Pearson) is less informative than rank correlation (Spearman) regarding the information presented to the learner.

All in all, yes, it is a bit unusual to have such a extreme behaviour (70% going to 0% in terms of importance) but if the improvements in our metric of including `X2` are always outperformed by including `X1` *and* `X1` interacts similarly with `X2` with the other feature variables, *and* those `X2:Xn` interactions are not informative towards our end goal than `X1:Xn` sure... it can happen. :)